# color profiles half installed on big screen | U20.04 -> U22.04

Tags: 22.04, color-management

After upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 I have a strange behavior on my LG 34WK95U. The screen is fed via Thunderbolt cable from a Dell XPS 15 9560. The screen resolution is 5120x2160. The display server is Xorg. The color profiles of the left and right parts of the screen are different, as in the screen photo.

[image: 1]

interestingly, only the red channel seems to be affected. The black & white version looks fine.

Comment: Wayland or xorg? Those kinds of big screens are actually treated as two separate screens in terms of the connection btw, so that's why only half of the screen is affected

Comment: Hi, forgot to mention - it`s Xorg. Maybe i should try wayland as well